# Solving 2d vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

---

1) Find an equation for the line with vector form <5,-2>, + t<2,6> in the form y = mx + b

For this I had no idea how to do

2) Find the value of k such that <-2,k> is the vector of the line with the equation y = (4x+1)/7

For this one I thought that k was equal to -1 after plugging -2 in for x but it's incorrect.

Plz help, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know how to find an equation of a line in the form $y=mx+b$ if you know the coordinates of two points on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If a line is given by $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle p,q\rangle+t\langle a,b\rangle$,

then two points on the line $(t=0$ and $t=1)$ are $\langle p,q\rangle$ and $\langle p+a,q+b\rangle$,

so the slope of the line is $\dfrac{(q+b)-q}{(p+a)-p}=\dfrac ba$.

Comment: Thank you I resulted with y = 3x -17, could you help me and tell what was wrong with 2?

Comment: $y=3x-17$ is correct; for 2, the slope is $\dfrac 47$, so set that equal to $\dfrac k{-2}$